# MySql Old Version django-mysql field incompatible

Tags: python, django

I was trying to add django-mysql app in my project
https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html#jsonfields-in-forms

It worked perfectly on my local system. But When I ran it into production, it created an error

> (django_mysql.E016) MySQL 5.7+ is required to use JSONField
>     HINT: At least one of your DB connections should be to MySQL 5.7+

What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message and the [`django-mysql` documentation for `JSONField`](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html) quite plainly says, you'll (or your friendly system administrator will) need to upgrade your production database server to MySQL 5.7 or newer.

Comment: Isn;t there any other option?

Comment: No. JSON fields are a MySQL 5.7+ feature. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Comment: Can the production system break if I try to upgrade MySql?

Comment: Anything can happen and not knowing anything about the particular system, I'm not going to recommend any actions. Upgrading MySQL is beyond the scope of this question, anyway.

Comment: If you don't need the JSON lookup features, though, you can look into https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonfield/ instead.

Comment: lookup was the only reason I switched from django-jsonfield to django_mysql